# Amount of TCP connections socket.io using namespaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

When I have the following express app (code snippet only shows code of interest):

**Backend express server:**

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   ...logic...
});

const nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');
nsp.on('connection', (socket) => {
  ...logic...
});
```

**Front end**

```
const socket1 = io();

const socket2 = io('/my-namespace');
```

My current understanding is that this will create only one TCP connection. Does connecting to multiple namespaces create multiple TCP connections or does it use one TCP connection?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested. Different namespaces are sitting on one websocket connection (thus one TCP connection).

You can see a websocket connection being made in the network tab (chrome devtools this example) like this:

[image: namespaces TCP connections socket.io]

We can see in the above illustration that one websocket connection is made because there is one Type `websocket`.